# Regular Expression to match dot separated list with no dot on the end and allow asterisk at the end

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following input strings and I need a regex to validate the input.

```
test.test = OK
test.test.1 = OK
test.text* = OK

test.test. = NO
test.test.* = NO
test = NO
```

This is my regex, it works but does not successful validate the input as wished:

```
^[a-z0-9*.\-_\.:]+$
```

How can I get it work?

Comment: What is the second regex? It is not quite clear what the rule related to `*` is. I tried now with `^(?!.*[.*]{2})[a-z0-9*_:-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9*_:-]+)+$`, no idea if you meant that `.` and `*` cannot appear next to each other (or consecutive `.` and `*` are not allowed). You say *allow asterisk at the end*, but you also state that `test.test.*` is a no match.

Comment: Could you clarify the criteria for your regex, please? It's not this obvious.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex is working. Please put is as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*[.*]{2})[a-z0-9*_:-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9*_:-]+)+$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%5b.*%5d%7b2%7d%29%5ba-z0-9*_%3a-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5ba-z0-9*_%3a-%5d%2b%29%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=test.test%0d%0atest.test.1%0d%0atest.text*%0d%0a%0d%0atest.test.%0d%0atest.test.*%0d%0atest&o=m) (at regexstorm, line endings are CRLF and `\r?` is used for the multiline string demo purpose only).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*[.*]{2})` - no two consecutive `.` and `*` are allowed
- `[a-z0-9*_:-]+` - 1 or more ASCII lowercase letters, digits, `*`, `_`, `:` or `-`
- `(?:\.[a-z0-9*_:-]+)+` - 1 or more consecutive occurrences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[a-z0-9*_:-]+` - 1 or more ASCII lowercase letters, digits, `*`, `_`, `:` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this will solve your problem.**

```
^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+((\.[a-z0-9]+)|\*)?$
```

> Explanation

`^` - Start of the string.

`[a-z0-9]` - any of the character in this range will be valid.

`+` - One or more.

`\.` -  Matches literal . (period).

`((\.[a-z0-9]+)|\*)?` -

```
    (\.[a-z0-9]+) - this sub-group checks for . followed by any digit or characters
    \*         - matches for asterisk
    ?          - make the preceding group optional.
```

`$` - Anchor to the end of line

Comment: It checks for all the cases what user asked for.
let the OP checks and come-up with requirements if it doesn't  serve what he asked for.
**Am i supposed to write a regex which matches every pattern of world ?**
I think you should read the comments of again *Wiktor* @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi

Comment: Well, OP didn't ask to write a regex that matches every pattern of world as that is trivial which is `.*` OP was very clear in stating **dot separated list** and `test.test.test` is a simple dot separated list which should match. Even Wiktor's or mine answer also matches that simple text but yours doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

From your given valid and invalid sample of text, I am concluding following things,

1. The text will contain word characters.
2. The word characters can be separated by single dot. Like this `abc.xyz` or `aaa.bbb.ccc`
3. Dot character can't be the first or last character. This is not ok `.abc` or `abc.aaa.`
4. Optionally star (asterisk) character can only appear as the last character. Hence `test.text*` is fine because `test.text` is fine but `test.text.*` is not fine because `test.text.` is not fine.

Considering these rules, you can use following regex,

```
^\w+(\.\w+)*(?<!\.)[*]?$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> Start of string
- `\w+` --> match a word of one or more length
- `(\.\w+)*` --> Match further word characters zero or more preceded by a single literal dot zero or more times.
- `(?<!\.)[*]?` --> asterisk character can optionally be present at the end of string which should not be preceded by a literal dot
- `$` --> End of input.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nfZbIg/1)